# check to see if the word is in the array

Tags: java, loops

I have a method to check if the word is within the given array/ However, it could not give me the correct return value. Any suggestion?

```
words [] = {Dog, Cat, Fish, Horse};
WordList wl = new WordList();
if (wl.findWord("Cat") >= 0) {
     System.out.println("Cat is in the word list");
}
if (wl.findWord("Dog") >= 0) {
       System.out.println("Dog is in the word list");
}
public int findWord(String w) {
    // Loop over all words until w is found. Return index of w, or -1 if not found
    int numb = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
       if (w.equals(words[i])) {   
           numb = i;
           break;
       } else {
           return numb = -1;
       }
    }
    return numb;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger, and step through the code, and you will understand. But the first step would be to indent your code, so that you can read it. The structure matters. Hint: what does `return` do?

Comment: its because you are returning in one iteration, also please format your code

Answer (score 2):

Your code properly indented looks like

```
int numb = 0;

for( int i= 0; i <= count; i++)  {
    if (w.equals(words[i])) {
        numb = i;
        break;
    } else
        return numb = -1;
}
return numb;
```

What do you think happens if the first word does not match the search? *Hint*: it returns -1 immediately. Solution: drop the `else` block completely.

Further improvements: `return` inside the `if` instead of setting a local variable and `break`ing.

---

I do not know what `count` is, but `<=` looks dangerous to cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Dropping the else block is not sufficient, though. It would return 0 for "not found".

Comment: @JBNizet sure, dropping the `else` block and dropping the local variable will cause OP to think about what to return in case the for loop does not `return`

Comment: the count is given:

Comment: words = new String[2];
  count = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `numb` with `-1` instead and only return outside of your loop. You should also take care of your bounds. The condition should read `i < count`, or else you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (assuming `count` holds the size of your array).

```
int numb = -1;

for(int i= 0; i < count; i++)  {
    if (w.equals(words[i])) {
        numb = i;
        break;
    }
}
return numb;
```

If you want you can remove the local variable altogether if you return inside your loop once you've found the word.

```
for(int i= 0; i < count; i++)  {
    if (w.equals(words[i])) {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: I can only got the Dog to return but not the word Cat to be returned in the if statement

Comment: getting rid of local variable actually worked instead of declare int numb = -1. Thanks. Not sure why it is happening?